# Dual install Windows + Linux - how to start Linux via Grub?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, grub, uefi

I have installed Linux near my windows partition. My pc is from Acer firm with a Intel Core i3 2.4Ghz.

Windows 10 is installed on UEFI boot. I installed Linux on Legacy boot. Can't see the GRUB when I turn on my pc to choose on which OS I want to work. Every time I want work on Windows or Linux, I have to press F2 instead of choosing it directly from the GNU GRUB. What can I do?

PS: I installed Linux on Legacy boot because my USB boot did not work on UEFI boot.

Comment: Did you tell your BIOS to try legacy boot first?

Comment: Yes. But Windows is installed on UEFI

Comment: You should be able to boot from a USB drive in UEFI mode, though you may also need to turn off *Secure Boot*. See https://neosmart.net/wiki/enable-legacy-boot-mode/

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you please tell me how to tunr off Secure boot,? It's locked up.